# get activeIndex from p:accordionPanel in the same JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces, accordion, jsf-2.2

I want to know how to do show a panelgroup if is selected specific tab of accordionPanel Primefaces.

```
<p:accordionPanel id="myAccordion" activeIndex="1">
    <p:tab title="first" id="tab0">
        ...
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab title="second" id="tab2">
        ...
    </p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>


<h:panelGroup id="myPanelGroup" rendered="#{myAccordion.activeIndex=='0'}">
...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Thank you.

H

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check prime face showcase they have ajax event for your reference

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabbedView.onTabChange}" update=":form:msgs" />
<p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{tabbedView.onTabClose}" update=":form:msgs" />
```

Once you get your tab index you can do whatever you want to do and update your panel according your need.
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml